# How to take 1st 5(1-5) set of data from CSV file for 1st user in a loop and the next 2nd 5 set of data for 2nd user, and soo on for 3rd user in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Data in CSV :
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15

Element used in Jmeter : Loop Controller
But what is happening is, as first user is started, in the meanwhile second user has also started, so it is not taking data as expected

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV data really looks like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I think the only way is using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), example code would be something like:

```
 ${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().get(0).split(' ')[ctx.getThreadNum() * 5..4 + ctx.getThreadNum() * 5],)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: no it was just to explain, my data is the policies like D612678
D612863
D612790
D612604
D565587
D564568
D559184
D556695

Comment: I have taken a loop controller for it

Comment: Does loop controller can help me out?

Comment: how to CHECK with this data